# Java Optional params good practice

Tags: java

I was told that this approach:

```
public class Example{

private String field

Optional<String> getField(){
   return Optional.of(field);
  }
}
```

is better than this:

```
public class Example{
  Optional<String> field;
}
```

My question is why?

Comment: Other than what the title suggests, the difference between the two approaches is not the use of *Optional* but rather whether to use a getter or direct field access. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: `return Optional.of(field);` makes no sense. you probably meant `return Optional.ofNullable(field);`